# how to make spaces in sb.append?

Tags: java

i use this code to parse many values from a JSONArray but i want to make new line between all these values like the caracatere \n that we use to make space  between many String

```
JSONArray precisions = deals.getJSONArray(TAG_PRECISION);
            for(int j  =0 ; j < precisions.length(); j++ ){
                sb.append(precisions.getString(j));
            }
           final  String Precision = sb.toString();
```

Comment: If you can append a result, why can't you figure out how to append a space?

Answer (score 1):

Either insert the spaces yourself:

```
for(int j=0; j < precisions.length(); j++ ){
    sb.append(precisions.getString(j)).append(' ');
}
```

Or use [a better tool for the job](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html).

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
 JSONArray precisions = deals.getJSONArray(TAG_PRECISION);
            for(int j  =0 ; j < precisions.length(); j++ ){
                sb.append(precisions.getString(j)).append("\n");
            }
           final  String Precision = sb.toString();
```

Comment: hey you are saying space but you asked behavious like '\n'.wrong question(misleading).Try my edited answer.